# Validate url parameter in the web socket Handshake - Play scala

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.3

I am developing a web socket method using scala language in Play Framework 2.3. I have the below code to validate the user in the web socket.

```
   def speak = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    Future.successful(request.session.get("user") match {
      case None    => Left(Forbidden)
      case Some(_) => Right(SpeakWs.props _)
    })
  }
```

But I want to validate "session_id" in the database that is passed from the web socket URL. My web socket call is like below.

```
ws://localhost:9000/speak?session_id=dsf76asdfasdeqrweqr34
```

I can get the session_id from the URL in the web socket as below.

```
   def speak = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    var session_id = getSessionIdFromURL(request.uri)
    ...
  }

  def getSessionIdFromURL(url: String) = {
    var splitedPath: Array[String] = new Array[String](2)
    splitedPath = url.split("=")

    val session_id: String = splitedPath(1)
  }
```

How do I validate the session_id in the DB and do the handshake if it is valid?

(i.e) Instead of "request.session.get("user") match", how do I validate session_id?

I am new to the development. So I didn't know how to do this...

Anybody help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def speak = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    Future.successful(request.session.get("user") match {
      case None    => Left(Forbidden)
      case Some(_) => 
        validateSessionId(request.uri) match {
            case true => Right(SpeakWs.props _)
            case false => Left(Forbidden)
        }
    })
  }
```

Also add another method to validate the session id in the database.

```
def validateSessionId(uri: String): Boolean = {
    val sessionId = getSessionIdFromUrl(uri)
    databaseConnector.findSessionById(sessiondId).map {
        case true => true
        case false => false
    }
}
```

You haven't specified what driver you are using so you will have to figure out the implementation yourself I'm afraid. If you put these details in your question I can help with that too.

You don't need to initialise the `splittedPath` variable in your getSessionFromUrl method either, you can do something similar to below and the compiler will infer the type:

```
def getSessionIdFromURL(url: String) = {
    val splitedPath = url.split("=")
    splitedPath(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I 'll try it.